# 19.10: Ubuntu runs 3 hours on a battery charge, Windows gets about 9 hours

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, power-management, battery

I recently dualbooted my laptop (Huawei matebook x pro i7-8550U, 16ram, nvidia mx150) for the first time (Ubuntu 19.10). I had few problems with it but i managed to resolve all of them expect the battery performance. On windows my laptop works for ~9h and on linux less than 3h. I have read that battery on linux should last longer and and on my perticular model even up to 11h. Any solution? Thanks in advance!

On the occasion, 4 more problems:

1. Fans are often running for no reason.
2. Performance is no as good as I expected, my specs are more than capable and still Ubuntu performs poorly.
3. Fingerprint GUI doesn't find my fingerprint reader.
4. Ubuntu doesn't remember my resolution and position of second screen, I have o set it manually every time I plug it in.

DRIVERS:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
Subsystem: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. UHD Graphics 620
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. GP108M [GeForce MX150]
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Toshiba America Info Systems Device 0116
```

Comment: What driver are you using for the Nvidia GPU? If you don't know how to check it just open a terminal and run `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`. Then edit your post with the output.

Comment: I did what you asked for :)

Answer (score 2):

For now let's try with the GPU driver.
Nvidia works a bit different on GNU/Linux compared to windows. First install the Nvidia official drivers. Open a terminal and run `ubuntu-drivers devices`. It might take a while. You should get a list like this one:

`$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000174Dsv00001025sd00001218bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM108M [GeForce MX150]
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin`

So, let's focus on the `recommended` driver. In this case is `nvidia-driver-440 - third-party free recommended` (You should get that one too). Open a terminal and run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-XXX` (Replace the XXX with the number you got before. When it's done just reboot your laptop. (In this case it would be `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440`)

Once you log in again you should have a new desktop app called *Nvidia X Server Settings*. There is where you can set up your Nvidia GPU. (Similar to Windows).

Now we can work on the the really important thing: battery performance.
On the *Nvidia X Server Settings* you should get an option called *PRIME Settings*. (If you don't, simply install it running `sudo apt install nvidia-prime`). There is where you can select what GPU you want to use. For a better battery performance select the Intel GPU, then reboot your laptop.

After all this process it's normal your laptop fan is turned on. Rebooting, installing drivers and the Nvidia GPU heats up almost any laptop. Just leave your laptop alone some time so it can cool down a bit.

If you want to know your laptop's CPU temperature install lm-sensors by running `sudo apt install lm-sensors`. Then run the command `sensors`.

Please let me know if this has been useful to you.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you afford, I really apreshiate it! Unfortunately it didnt help, after following the instructions the laptops shows 2,5h of battery life with 90%. The only thing that differed was the Nvidia X Server Setting options, on the list I can only see PRIME Profiles not PRIME Settings, although in PRIME Profiles there is "Select the GPU you would like to use" and i selected Intel (Power Saving Mode)

Comment: A thing that comes in pair with poor battery life is that it charges very slowly, I though it might help

Comment: Aslo, i think the problem with fan turning on lies deeper, it turns on while watching youtube video

Comment: Fine, now install tlp running `sudo apt install tlp`. 
Basically tlp helps to extend battery life without any further setup. After you install it reboot your laptop. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Usually high quality video heats up a bit the GPU, so the fan is turned on at slow speed.

Comment: It never happened to me on windows

Comment: Also remember that when your laptop is plugged in it will definitely get hotter compared to battery mode. This is because by default Ubuntu does not restrict the CPU at all when it detects the laptop is plugged in, so you get a better performance.

Comment: I had tlp installed before I wrote this post, it didnt help :(

Comment: When I unplug the charger when the laptop has 100% ubuntu shows that 10h are ramaining but after 1sec it changes to significantly lower value like 3h

Comment: Could you please try to measure how long does your battery takes to empty? Just use your laptop as usual and ignore battery percentage. Is there that considerable time difference from Windows to Ubuntu?

Comment: Usually almost any OS measures the reaming battery time according to the tasks you are running. E.g. You are reading some articles on Firefox while you listen some music and then you decided to play Outlast with the Nvidia GPU. In the first situation you will get more time than in the second one.

Comment: On windows I can easily get even 8h programming while listening to music and researching some stuff on the internet. And ubuntu lasts for around 2-3h. Today to drained from 100 to 40 in just an hour while I was trying to resolve this problem

Comment: And I have read that other Ubuntu users of the Huawei Matebook x pro get even 10h of constant use